# Meta tag: do I use name or id?

Tags: html, tags, metadata, meta

I saw that in HTML5, you don't use the `name` attribute, but use the `id` attribute, instead. I also saw that you write metadata with the `name` attribute. So which one of them should I use while writing metadata?

```
<meta name="" content="">
```

OR

```
<meta id="" content="">`
```

Comment: I would prefer the id-tag. I did this in my html documents multiple times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> you don't use the name attribute, but use the id attribute

This only applies to `a` elements (whose `name` attribute is deprecated in favor of giving the closest element a corresponding ID). It doesn't apply to any other element with a `name` attribute, neither `input`, nor `meta`. In other words, you *cannot* replace the `name` attribute with an ID for any other element. Anyone suggesting otherwise is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

According to:

- [W3C reference](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/meta)
- [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_meta.asp)
- [Google structured data documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#using-meta-tags)
- [Mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)

the `name` attribute has to be used in `<meta>` tags and not the `id`, in this context, because `name` is the attribute which **defines the name of the metadata** you will set in the `content` attribute.

`id` attribute has a [different meaning](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute): it is used to **give a unique identifier** to a HTML element to be referenced in stylesheets, scripts, anchor links, etc.

Comment: 'trivial' means 'of no consequence'. If one attribute is required in a `<meta>` tag in place of another attribute, I'd say that's fairly consequential. What did you mean to say there?

Comment: I mean according to the references it is *obvious* (maybe it is a better word? :)) to me that `name` attribute has to be used and not `id` in the context defined by the question. (I've just edited my answer, I hope I could improved its quality.)

Comment: Ah, so you meant it should trivial for the OP to learn why, rather than having to ask a question on Stack Overflow.